# pandas dataframe join with where restriction

Tags: python, join, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas DataFrames looking like this:

*ranks*:

```
year     name      rank    
2015     A         1         
2015     B         2         
2015     C         3         
2014     A         4         
2014     B         5         
2014     C         6
```

and *tourneys*:

```
date         name       
20150506     A              
20150708     B         
20150910     C           
20141212     A             
20141111     B              
20141010     C
```

I want to join these two DataFrames based on the `name` column, however as you can see the names are not unique and are repeated each year. Hence a restriction for the join is that the `year` of *ranks* should match the first four characters of `date` of *tourneys*.

the result should look like this:

```
date         name_t  year   name_r    rank        
20150506     A       2015     A       1             
20150708     B       2015     B       2           
20150910     C       2015     C       3          
20141212     A       2014     A       4           
20141111     B       2014     B       5             
20141010     C       2014     C       6
```

I am aware of the `join` method in pandas, however, I would also need to restrict the join with some sort of `WHERE ranks.year == tourneys.date[:4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `date4` for `df2` and then merge `df1` and `df2`

```
In [103]: df2['date4'] = (df2['date']/10000).astype(int)
```

Now, merge `df1` and `df2` on `['year', 'name']` and `['date4', 'name']` combinations.

```
In [104]: df1.merge(df2, left_on=['year', 'name'], right_on=['date4', 'name'])
Out[104]:
   year name  rank      date  date4
0  2015    A     1  20150506   2015
1  2015    B     2  20150708   2015
2  2015    C     3  20150910   2015
3  2014    A     4  20141212   2014
4  2014    B     5  20141111   2014
5  2014    C     6  20141010   2014
```

Where `df1` and `df2` looks like

```
In [105]: df1
Out[105]:
   year name  rank
0  2015    A     1
1  2015    B     2
2  2015    C     3
3  2014    A     4
4  2014    B     5
5  2014    C     6

In [106]: df2
Out[106]:
       date name  date4
0  20150506    A   2015
1  20150708    B   2015
2  20150910    C   2015
3  20141212    A   2014
4  20141111    B   2014
5  20141010    C   2014
```

Comment: nice. i am trying it out right now. quick question: if df2 is much bigger than df1, should I do df2.merge(df1...) ? is it better resource-wise?

Comment: solution does not work for me right now. i think the problem is that `df1.year` is of type `object` and that `df2.date4` is of type `int32` in my data. how to avoid this?

Comment: ok I just converted `df1.year` column to int via `df1['year'] = df1['year'].astype(int)`. solution works now and is marked as accepted!